# Inserting the bulk data into different data tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 i am having two different databases in both the i am having a same table here i want to copy data from one database to another database

how can we this can be implemented in sql server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

if the two database is database1 and database2,the table name is Tablename,you can use:

```
Insert into dbo.database1.TableName select * from dbo.database2.Tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different methods for this.

1. Use DTS tool of SQL Server 2008.
2. INSERT INTO DBName.Schema.TableName
   SELECT F1,F2 FROM TableName